# Xcode 5 кнопка звука в приложении

Tags: xcode, objective-c, ios7

Добрый вечер! пытаюсь сделать кнопку звука в приложении (вкл/выкл).
Но мой код срабатывает только один раз - звук включает и все, просьба подсказать что не так)

```
- (IBAction)soundButton:(id)sender
{
    if (soundOn == NO) {
        soundOn = YES;
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone sound.png"];
        [_soundButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self soundPlay];
    }
    else {
        soundOn = NO;
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone sound off.png"];
        [_soundButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну в else явно не хватает какого-то вызова-антипода для [self soundPlay]. А то флаг Вы меняете и кнопку обновляете, а звук не выключаете

Comment: да, спасибо) действительно помогло))) голова уже совсем под вечер не варит) Еще раз благодарю!